# Use Hibernate to find the data,but it alerts "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is the exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

This is the code:
   Only the function "getByReportDate" is written by myself, the othes are generated by hibernate.I used the same way to operate another java model, it succeed.But when comes to the one,it failed.

```
//DAO
public static final String REPTIME = "reportTime";

public List getByReportDate(Object recOrgName) {
    return findByProperty(REPTIME, recOrgName);
}

public List findByProperty(String propertyName, Object value) {
  log.debug("finding TblEntPaytaxList instance with property: " + propertyName
        + ", value: " + value);
  try {
     String queryString = "from TblEntPaytaxList as model where model." 
                            + propertyName + "= ?";
     return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString, value);
  } catch (RuntimeException re) {
     log.error("find by property name failed", re);
     throw re;
  }
}


//Object
public class TblEntPaytaxList  implements java.io.Serializable {

 ...
 private String econType;
 private Date reportTime;
 private double money;
 ...
```

Comment: EntityManager has closed the session. Open a session.

Comment: So where to open a seesion?

Comment: Open session using hibernate.

Comment: You need to carefully read the [Spring Framework ORM Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm)

Comment: Like this?:public List getByReportDate(Object recOrgName) {Session session = this.getSession();
    return findByProperty(REPTIME, recOrgName);
}

Comment: Should I release it after "findByProperty"?

Comment: Paste the complete stacktrace & hibernate configuration file. Also are there only 3 properties in the TblEntPaytaxList  class?